# Carga de elemento enviados por ng-click desde un textarea a través de un ID

Tags: angularjs

Lo que quiero es que al hacer click en el botton me envie el comentario y lo cargue en su respectivo id algo asi como en Jqueryque cargas dicho elementos mediante un ID `$("#commentload" + id).append(template);`

Dejo mi codigo AngularJS (Angular 1) ya que e intentado hacerlo de varias formas y aun no e tenido exito en lo que quiero

```
this.sendComments = (stream_id) => {
    let data = {
        stream_id: stream_id,
        body: this.commentBody
    }
    this.CommentService.getComments(data).then((response) => {
        this.comments.push(response.data);
        angular.element('').find(...)
    }).catch(this.failedComment.bind(this));

    this.commentBody = "";
}


<div flex-gt-sm="100" flex>
    <md-divider ></md-divider>
    <md-list flex ng-repeat="cmt in streams['comments']">
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="comentarios in cmt">
            <img ng-src="{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_avatar_mini']}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_name']}}" />
             <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
               <h3>{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_name']}} - {{comentarios['comment_created_at']}}</h3>
                 <p>{{comentarios['comment_body']}}</p>
             </div>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
     </md-list>



    <md-list flex>
    <!--Aqui cargo los comentarios enviados desde el input-->
        <md-list-item id="stream-{{streams.stream_id}}" class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="comments in stream['comments']">
            <img ng-src="{{comments[0]['users']['data']['user_avatar_mini']}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{comments[0]['data']['users']['data']['user_name']}}" />
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
              <h3>{{comments[0]['users']['data']['user_name']}} - {{comments[0]['comment_created_at']}}</h3>
              <p>{{comments[0]['comment_body']}}</p>
            </div>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
</div>

<md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" flex>
        <label>Comenta!</label>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="stream.commentBody">
        <md-icon md-font-set="md" style="display:inline-block;" ng-click="stream.sendComments(streams.stream_id)">send</md-icon><!--Cuando haga click cargue el comentario en el id especifico del stream-->
    </md-input-container>
</md-card-actions>
```

En `id="stream-{{streams.stream_id}}"` es donde quiero realizar dicha carga de comentario enviado de acuerdo a los stream cargador en una lista si son 30 con diferentes ID y distintos comentarios cargue el comentario a su id correspondiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinion personal, no trabajo con `id` cuando trabajo con angularjs, mas bien con `ng-model` por lo tanto si tu quisieras que al hacer click en un boton se carguen datos , si es un arreglo de comentarios :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="comentario" placeholder="ingrese comentario"/>
<button ng-click="actualizar()">Comentar</button>
<div ng-repeat="comentario in comentarios">
  <p>{{comentario}}</p>
</div>

$scope.actualizar = function(){
    $scope.comentarios.push($scope.comentario);
}
```

Al trabajar con `ng-model` tienes la ventaja de que no es necesario hacer un `append` de tu elemento `html`, ademas los valores al hacer `push` desde el controlador se actualizan inmediatamente en la vista.

Comment: Si pero resulta que en la lista de stream se carga más de un stream (Publicación ) el cual tienen para comentar y también para eliminar y editar solo que cuando se comenta si hay diez publicaciones al comentar la última el comentario aparece en todas las demás es por ello que quiero especificar a que elemento del DOM debe agregarse no se si me entiendes bien lo que quiero realizar con esto

Comment: Y si agrega un comentario a la publicacion (stream) cual es el comportamiento apropiado del comentario? Porque si quieres especificar que el comentario quede en un elemento en especifico, en ese elemento debes trabajar con el ng-model no se si me explico

Comment: El stream como tal es un timeline lleno de publicaciones estilo Facebook como cuando agregas un comentario a tu publicación se agrega directamente a ella y no a las demás ese es el comportamiento que quiero del comentario en cambio en mi web se hace en todas no debería reflejarse en todas si no en la que se comenta solamente claro en el Backend se agrega a una sola publicacion pero en el frontend se hace en todas y no es lo correcto debería ser solo s la que se comenta

Comment: Es que en ese caso el comentario deberia hacer referencia a una publicacion y no a cualquiera. Por ende un comentario haria referencia a una publicacion id o algo parecido.

Comment: <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" flex>
        <label>Comenta!</label>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="stream.commentBody">
        <md-icon md-font-set="md" style="display:inline-block;" ng-click="stream.sendComments(streams.stream_id)">send</md-icon><!--Cuando haga click cargue el comentario en el id especifico del stream-->
    </md-input-container>
</md-card-actions> Si y eso hago allí stream.sendComments(streams.stream_id) y aun no se porque me actualiza el comentario en todas las publicaciones

Comment: Hice un codepen, puedes verlo y ver si te sirve algo asi? Lo voy a editar en mi pregunta http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/ZBOPJg

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48549/discussion-between-sioesi-and-vdjkelly).

Comment: ok probaré tu ejemplo y te diré como me fue cualquier duda te preguntare sobre el tema gracias

Comment: @vdjkelly estoy en el chat!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias me sirvio de mucho tu ejemplo

```
this.sendComments = (stream_id, streams) => {
            let data = {
                stream_id: stream_id,
                body: this.comentario
            }
            this.CommentService.getComments(data).then((response) => {
                streams.comments.data.push(response.data);
            }).catch(this.failedComment.bind(this));

            this.comentario = "";

        }


<div flex-gt-sm="100" flex>
                  <md-divider ></md-divider>
                  <md-list flex ng-repeat="comentarios in streams.comments.data">
                      <md-list-item class="md-3-line">
                          <img ng-src="{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_avatar_mini']}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_name']}}" />
                          <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                            <h3>{{comentarios['users']['data']['user_name']}} - {{comentarios['comment_created_at']}}</h3>
                              <p>{{comentarios['comment_body']}}</p>
                          </div>
                        <md-divider></md-divider>
                      </md-list-item>

                 </md-list>
          </div>

          <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
              <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" flex>
                  <label>Comenta!</label>
                  <input type="text" data-ng-model="stream.comentario">
                  <md-icon md-font-set="md" style="display:inline-block;" ng-click="stream.sendComments(streams.stream_id, streams)">send</md-icon>
              </md-input-container>

          </md-card-actions>
```

Dejo el codigo para quien le sirva de ejemplo